# Attach different functions to dynamically created card

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I have a card list that is being created by looping through some JSON data which is stored on Firebase. Each card is split in two parts: "overviewCardInfo" and "overviewCardOptions".

I would like to make it so that when the options part is clicked, a function is called (in this case a .toggleClass()) and when the info part is clicked, the title of that card is displayed somewhere else.

So far I have been unable to achieve either effect: The title of the card is nowhere to be seen and the toggleClass() either affects the div with class ".overviewCardOptions" or affects all cards rather than just the one clicked.

This is what the JSON array I am taking from Firebase to generate the cards looks like:

```
[{"name":"Push Ups", "duration":3, "break":3},{"name":"Squats", "duration":3, "break":3},{"name":"Running in Place", "duration":3, "break":3}]
```

JavaScript (some jQuery):

```
  // Compile Routine Overview List.
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.exercise); // The JSON shown above
  obj.forEach(function(exercise)
  {
    $("#overviewList").append("<li><div class='overviewCard'><div class='overviewCardInfo'>\n\
    <h3>" + exercise.name + "</h3><p>" + exercise.duration + " sec.</p><p id='right'>Break: " + exercise.break + " sec.</p>\n\
    </div><div class='overviewCardOptions'><img src='images/thrash.png' width='23' alt='' /></div></div></li>");
  });

$(document).on("click", ".overviewCardInfo", function() // Attach event handler to document, as cards are generated after other elements on page.
  {
    $("#overviewSpecifier").css("display", "block"); // Works fine.
    $("#infoP").text($(this).text()); // Shows all text contained in card, of course, how do I target the h3 tag specifically? jQuery API docs not helping me understand atm.
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".overviewCardOptions", function()
  {
    $(".overviewCard", this).toggleClass("toDelete"); // Fails.
  });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="overviewList"></ul>

<div id="overviewSpecifier">
  <p id="infoP"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you need? bind another event handler `$(".overviewCardInfo").on("click", function(){ ....... });`

Comment: I think I was not clear in describing my problem. I have edited my question, please take another look!

Comment: `$(this).prev(".overviewCard").toggleClass("toDelete");`

Comment: @Satpal sorry, that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the `click()` event to the `document` instead to make it global.

```
$(document).on("click", ".overviewCardOptions", handleThrashClick);
```

Also, your object (in fact it's an array) shouldn't have quotation marks

`var obj = "[ ... ]"` should be `var obj = [ ... ]`

See demo here >> https://fiddle.jshell.net/9a457qzv/3/

Comment: I think I was not clear in describing my problem. I have edited my question, please take another look!

Comment: @Brian - Se the updated Fiddle, is that what you're after?

Comment: I marked your answer as THE answer because it fixed my main problem, however I can't help but notice that your handleThrashClick function has the same problem as mine: it only deletes the image of the thrash icon, or the overviewCardOptions div once clicked, not the whole card. Do you know how I might achieve this? Thanks for your help so far anyway.